# Subject-verb agreement with infinitive

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, infinitives

> Physical activity has the potential to improve the physical and mental health of people, **reduce** all kinds of chronic diseases causing mortality and **improve** life expectancy.

> Physical activity has the potential to improve the physical and mental health of people, **reduces** all kinds of chronic diseases causing mortality and **improves** life expectancy

Which one if correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct, but they say different things. The first says that physical activity has the potential to do three things - improve health, reduce diseases, and improve life expectancy. The second is saying three things about physical activity - that it has the potential to improve health, that it reduces diseases, and that it improves life expectancy.

In this example the second statement is stronger than the first - the last part is saying that physical activity does actually improve life expectancy, not just that it has the potential to do improve life expectancy.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

> Physical activity has the potential to [**improve** the physical and mental health of people], [**reduce** all kinds of chronic diseases causing mortality] and [**improve** life expectancy].

2. 

> Physical activity [*has* the potential to improve the physical and mental health of people], [**reduces** all kinds of chronic diseases causing mortality] and [**improves** life expectancy].

I have placed brackets for ease of comparison.  With the brackets placed this way, we have subject-verb agreement.

Some people may interpret the sentences as having the brackets placed according to example (1).  This would lead to perceived grammatical errors in example (2).

To express that reductions of all kinds of chronic diseases causing mortality and improvements to life expectancy are real rather than just potential benefits, to overcome ambiguity, we could change the order of the items in example (2).

> Physical activity [**reduces** all kinds of chronic diseases causing mortality], [**improves** life expectancy] and  [*has* the potential to improve the physical and mental health of people].